# Two extra columns with using HAVING in QoQ Coldfusion

Tags: sql, coldfusion, having, qoq

When I use HAVING in my QoQ coldfusion, the query returned will have two extra column: "Column_7" and "Column_8"

The original resultat
[image]

And the resultat with two extra columns
[image]

Here is my code

```
var qEffectifTemp = queryExecute("
 SELECT CONVIVETYPELABEL, 
    SUM(EFFECTIFITEMVALEURPREVISIONNELLE) AS REPASPREVISIONNELLETOTAL, 
    SUM(EFFECTIFITEMVALEURSAISIE) AS REPASSAISIETOTAL, 
    OFFICENAME, 
    SATELLITENAME,
    REPASTYPELABEL,
    CUISINECENTRALENAME
 FROM   qEffectifsItemTemp
 GROUP BY REPASTYPELABEL, SATELLITENAME, CONVIVETYPELABEL, OFFICENAME, CUISINECENTRALENAME
 HAVING SUM(EFFECTIFITEMVALEURPREVISIONNELLE) <> SUM(EFFECTIFITEMVALEURSAISIE)", {}, {dbtype="query"}
);
```

So why? Thank you for your helps

Comment: Will your query execute if you use the alias names from the select clause in the having clause?

Comment: Your two unnamed columns are likely because of the two un-aliased `sum()`s in your `HAVING`. Are they causing an issue?  Also, is a QoQ necessary here? More often than not, what the QoQ is doing can be done in the original query.

Comment: What flavor and version of SQL is your base table? And how many rows are in that table?

Comment: Yes @Shawn. The cause of problem is in aliased only. Please see my answer below . I've explained about root causes of problem.

Comment: @Kannan.P Oddly enough, in most logical query processing engines, a `HAVING` is evaluated BEFORE the `SELECT`, so a `SELECT` aliased column _shouldn't_ be able to be referenced in the `HAVING`. I think MySQL has some odd abilities to reference out of logical cycle, and we _are_ talking about a QoQ here, so pretty much all bets are off. :-/  I still say it may be possible to do what needs to be done in a single query, depending on how else the original query is used.

Comment: @Shawn. How ever we should give a solution for Column_1 issues. We don't know what his business to handle. May be for their business logic they might wrote a QoQ. So better go with my suggestion to solve the problem for now. Actually it's easy and proper way too.

Comment: I'm usually of the opinion that if a QoQ can be avoided, then it should be. In my experience, QoQ is used, more often than not, to solve a query programmatically rather than in the database where it should be. I don't know this application, so I can't say if a QoQ is necessary here, but I still say that the inconsistent "SQL" of QoQ can lead to some bad habits or confusing results. In most major flavors of SQL (except MySQL/Maria & SQLLite) an alias isn't available in the `HAVING` clause. So that habit could easily lead to questions as to why that same pattern doesn't work in the base query.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ef9bb402d7bd03d9499e4ba23c5e4a23

Comment: Agreed.  Adobe alludes to the fact that QoQ's use non-standard syntax in the "Using group by and having expressions" section, but ... ugh.  Once again, QoQ's doing the unexpected..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are not using the aliases properly.

This sample query produces the same issue:

```
<cfquery  name="childQuery" dbtype="query">
    SELECT sum(age) as Total, lastname FROM parentQuery
    GROUP BY id,lastname
    HAVING sum(age) > 10
</cfquery>
```

[image: Image of extra column]

Using the aliases in the HAVING clause, like in the below query, resolves the issue:

```
 <cfquery  name="childQuery" dbtype="query">
        SELECT sum(age) as Total, lastname FROM parentQuery
        GROUP BY id,lastname
        HAVING Total > 10
    </cfquery>
```

[image: Image of result, without extra columns]

Your problem is you already created aliases for the columns in the sql:

```
, SUM(EFFECTIFITEMVALEURPREVISIONNELLE) AS REPASPREVISIONNELLETOTAL 
, SUM(EFFECTIFITEMVALEURSAISIE) AS REPASSAISIETOTAL
```

Using the SUM's again in the `HAVING` clause creates extra columns like `column_7` & `column_8`.  Instead, you should use the aliases:

```
HAVING REPASPREVISIONNELLETOTAL <> REPASSAISIETOTAL
```

So your full query should look like the one below:

```
var qEffectifTemp = queryExecute("
         SELECT CONVIVETYPELABEL, 
            SUM(EFFECTIFITEMVALEURPREVISIONNELLE) AS REPASPREVISIONNELLETOTAL, 
            SUM(EFFECTIFITEMVALEURSAISIE) AS REPASSAISIETOTAL, 
            OFFICENAME, 
            SATELLITENAME,
            REPASTYPELABEL,
            CUISINECENTRALENAME
         FROM   qEffectifsItemTemp
         GROUP BY REPASTYPELABEL, SATELLITENAME, CONVIVETYPELABEL, OFFICENAME, CUISINECENTRALENAME
         HAVING REPASPREVISIONNELLETOTAL <> REPASSAISIETOTAL", {}, {dbtype="query"}
        );
```